# How to get specific element from another component using ng-content

Tags: angular

I want to get an element from random.component and display it in the footer of my main modal component by selecting it somehow.

**random.component.html**

```
<div>random text</div>
<span projectThis>text text</span>
```

**usecase.component.html**

```
<modal>
   <random></random>
</modal>
```

I have tried this but it didn't work:

**modal.component.html**

```
<h5>Title</h5>
<div>Random long text</div>
<ng-content select="[projectThis]"></ng-content>
```

Also I've tried with different selector type - class name, role. When I remove the selector it displays the whole component but select is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the above will work, as the modal's content is a **component** and that is going to build dynamically.

I tried this way, have a look [Stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-child-element-example)

Basically, I got the random component reference in the modal component using `@ContentChild`, and in the random component got a reference to `projectThis` element, and finally displaying it using `renderer`

```
//Modal
<div #footer></div>


@ContentChild(RandomComponent) randomComponent: RandomComponent;
@ViewChild("footer") footer: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  setTimeout(x => {
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.footer.nativeElement,
      this.randomComponent.projectThis.nativeElement
    );
  });
}
```

---

```
//Random
<span #projectThis>text text</span>

@ViewChild("projectThis") projectThis: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

Got above idea from [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-viewchild-access-component)

Note: This is not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: It seems to work but I don't want to add code in the modal component for every "random component". I want modal component to be used in several angular apps.